# When downloading file from URL it starts playing in Media player but not downloading

Tags: java, android, web-hosting

I am trying to host some mp3 files on server and want to download in my mobile app using program. I have uploaded some mp3 files on my hosting server and trying to download using browser but instead of downloading file it starts playing in Media player by streaming and also when I try to download using Java code it gives me below error

`java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect`

```
    <html>
<head> </head>
<body>
<ul>
<li><a href="hare_krishana_a201701.mp3">Hare Krishna</a> </li>
<li><a href="sarveshaam_a201702.mp3">Sarvesham</a> </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Java.

```
URLConnection conn = new URL("http://www.acharyaviren.com/musicArchive/sarveshaam_a201702.mp3").openConnection();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

            OutputStream outstream = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Day1"));
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int len;
            while ((len = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                outstream.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
            outstream.close();
```

Please help me how I can achieve this

Comment: The way your browsers treats mp3 files are nothing you can change with java code. Is the ``ConnectException`` thrown in the line of ``openConnection``?

Comment: Connect exception is thrown during conn.getInputStream(). I plan to use in Android but here I first I am trying using java.